# How to import win32api

Tags: python, import, python-2.5

I'm trying to use some python-2.1 code to control another program (ArcGIS). The version of python I am using is 2.5. I am getting the following error message when I run the code.

```
<type'exceptions.ImportError'>: No module named win32api
Failed to execute (polyline2geonetwork2).
```

I tried installing pywin32-214.win32-py2.5.exe but I still get the same error message. I can't figure out if I need to do anything to my original python install so it knows that I have installed this.

I think the problematic part of my code is the following:

```
import win32com.client, sys, string, os, re, time, math

gp = win32com.client.Dispatch("esriGeoprocessing.GpDispatch.1")
conn = win32com.client.Dispatch(r'ADODB.Connection')
```

Thanks for your help - I am quite new to python.

Comment: start IDLE.  type import win32com.client and hit enter.  Do you get an error message?

Comment: Do you have a file called win32api.py? ? What is its full path? The directory that contains win32api.py must be in sys.path for Python to find it.

Comment: What version of ArcGIS are you using? Also is it the same version of ArcGIS you built the old script around? Also ESRI installs their own version of python from the get go for ArcGIS. Try launching the python executable from the ArcGIS\bin folder. ESRI changed certain parts of their Geoprocessor library, we had to do some serious rewriting of certain scripts to function properly with ArcGIS 9.3. Have you tried using the new syntax of ArcGIS 9.3 for python?

Comment: import win32.com works fine - I do not get an error message.

I found win32api.py here:
C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\isapi\test\build\bdist.win32\winexe\temp

Comment: I'm using ArcGIS 9.3, which is a different version. The script was built for v9.1

Comment: As far as I can tell, this question never actually had anything to do with 2.1 and was not, for example, specific to a feature added to the language between 2.1 and 2.5. It was just some kind of environment misconfiguration.

Answer (score 2):

Your sys.path is

```
['C:\\Documents and Settings\\david\\My Documents\\GIS_References\\public\\funconn_public', 'C:\\Python25\\Lib\\idlelib', 'C:\\Program Files\\ArcGIS\\bin', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\python25.zip', 'C:\\Python25\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python25\\lib', 'C:\\Python25\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python25\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python25', 'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Python25\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
```

and winapi.py is located in C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\isapi\test\build\bdist.win32\winexe\temp.

Notice that this directory is not listed in your sys.path. To get things working, you'll need to put C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\isapi\test\build\bdist.win32\winexe\temp in your sys.path.

It appears winapi.py is not yet installed. It is in a test\build...\temp directory.
I don't know much about Windows+Python. Maybe there is documentation that came with winapi.py which explains how the installation is suppose to be achieved.

A quick (but ugly) fix is to manually insert the needed directory into sys.path.
By this I mean, you can edit polyline2geonetwork.py and put

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\isapi\test\build\bdist.win32\winexe\temp')
```

near the top of the file.

Answer (score 1):

print out `sys.path` right before the import and make sure the path to `win32com` is in there

Comment: win32com is not there, even if I import it beforehand. win32 is though.